# Search and Transactions in Sharded Redis

Tags: redis, sharding, jedis

the question refers to the sharded configuration of redis. I have implemented a small test application in Java which creates 100.000 user hashes over Jedis in the form of user:userID. Each hash has the elements: name, phone, department, userID. I also created simple key-value pairs with the key phone:phone number which contains the userID whose phone number is the ID and sets for each department with the userIDs who work for that particular department. The two latter types I use only for seaching. These structures and the search are similar to [Searching in values of a redis db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193176/searching-in-values-of-a-redis-db).

In short, the data structures:

```
user:userID->{name, department, phone, userID}
department:department->([userID1, userID2,....])
phone:phone->userID
```

Use cases for the search:

1. access to user-hashes based on key i.e. userID
2. search for users with a phone number
3. search for all users of a department

Everything works all right in the **single instance** and **sharded** configuration but I would have the following questions:

- In the single instance configuration it is possible **to look for phone
  number with a wide card** e.g. with the **KEY** method but this is not
  available in the sharded configuration. How would it be possible to
  look for keys whose first part is known?
- The user ID is generated from a zset whose score is increased for
  userID. This can be doen **in a transaction for the single instance
  configuration** but transactions seem not to be supported for sharding
  configurations over jedis even if the participating keys are on the
  same instance. **How would it be possible to solve this problem if
  multiple client threads can also do the user creation?**

Thank you for your responses also in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For the 1st part of your question:

There is no magic here, if you want to search across all your shards, you have to iterate over all shards. Jedis don't have this method, but you could extend **ShardedJedis** to add it (untested):

```java
    public Set<String> keys(String pattern) {
    HashSet<String> found = new HashSet<String>();

    for (Jedis jedis : getAllShards()) {
        found.addAll(jedis.keys(pattern));
    }

    return found;
    }
```

#### For the 2nd part of your question:

AFAIK, Jedis doesn't support transactions when using Shards, even if you do force the related keys to be on the same shard (see [Jedis Advanced Usage](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage)).

This same link suggest a workaround that may apply for a few scenarios:

> **Mixed approach**
>
> If you want easy load distribution of ShardedJedis, but still need
>   transactions/pipelining/pubsub etc, you can also mix the normal and
>   the sharded approach: define a master as normal Jedis, the others as
>   sharded Jedis. Then make all the shards slaveof master. In your
>   application, direct your write requests to the master, the read
>   requests to ShardedJedis. Your writes don't scale anymore, but you
>   gain good read distribution, and you have
>   transactions/pipelining/pubsub simply using the master. Dataset should
>   fit in RAM of master. Remember that you can improve performance of the
>   master a lot, if you let the slaves do the persistance for the master!

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexandre. This was exectly what I would need!