# Extract some information from a Redis database

Tags: redis

I'm running a Game server which uses a Redis database. I'm not familiar with NoSQL Db's.

I'm trying to extract some information from this database but I can't find the commands to do it with redis-cli. For the purpose I've made screenshots using Fastoredis under Windows but the server is running under Debian and I'm using redis-cli as client (Sorry I havn't enough reputation to post image so here a links to my images).

[entityinfo](https://www.peons.fr/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/redis.png)

First I want to get from the "table" (don't know if I can call it a table) "entityinfo" all items having the EntityType=Ship. From these items I like to get the information "Shiptype", "EntityName" and "TribeID" (Doesn't show up on the screenshot). I want to save these information in a file called ship.txt.

[TribeID](https://www.peons.fr/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/redis1.png)

Then from a second table called "tribedata" I want to get all items with the information TribeID and TribeName. I want to save these information in a file called tribe.txt.

This is for a Game Server DB runing under Debian Stretch with latest redis-server (3.2.6) package installed.

I've already tried to use the command `redis-cli --csv lrange` but I don't really know how it works and that's why I get no results.

Answer (score 1):

You can search by values with Redis, but it will not be easy, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201310/4137368)

A more simple, but not efficient solution is to:

- Get all entityinfo keys
- Loop trough each key, get the value
- Store it into an array if it's a ship

Example Using Nodejs:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "redis": "2.8.0"
  }
}
```

```
const redis = require("redis");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const options = {
  url: "redis://localhost:6379"
};
const client = redis.createClient(options);
const keysAsync = promisify(client.keys).bind(client);
const hgetAllAsync = promisify(client.hgetall).bind(client);

const isBoat = entity => entity.EntityType && entity.EntityType === "Ship";

const main = async () => {
  const keys = await keysAsync("entityinfo:*");

  const ships = [];
  for (const [index, key] of keys.entries()) {
    const entity = await hgetAllAsync(key);

    if (isBoat(entity)) {
      ships.push({ type: entity.ShipType, name: entity.EntityName });
    }
  }

  console.log(`  >`, ships);
  process.exit(0);
};

try {
  main();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
}
```

I'm guessing that your game is Atlas, look at [this project](https://github.com/GrapeshotGames/AtlasMapViewer/blob/master/Src/tileServer.go#L136) it's an interactive Map Viewer for Atlas, done by Grapeshot. They are using another method (with scan), to loop trough each entities.

Comment: Sanghin thanks for your answer. Thx to you I had my script done.