# How can i search by value in Redis?

Tags: hash, redis

before. sorry about to my beginner English skill. i'm Korean very not well Eng.

So...
I'm finding method that how can i scan value in Redis.
Not key.

for example.
To look up on data in the hash, In Redis, you search by key.

However, I want to look up by value, not by key.
Can i able this in Redis ??

thank you~~~

Comment: Useful answers in this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193176/searching-in-values-of-a-redis-db

Comment: you should also check rediserch